# Next.js Error occurred prerendering page "/blog/[slug]"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to implement getStaticPaths with Next.js
I used both getStaticPaths and getStaticProps together so I can cache my dynamic blog post links.
It is working fine locally but whenever I build on Vercel I get this  error. Why ?:

```
    Error occurred prerendering page "/blog/[slug]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'featured_image' of undefined
    at ArticleTopBar (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/blog/[slug].js:320:22)
    at d (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at Object.renderPage (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:596:45)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/6859.js:603:19)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/_document.js:33:83)
    at Object.loadGetInitialProps (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/utils.js:69:29)
```

**blog/[slug].js**:

```
export async function getStaticPaths({ locales }) {
  const articles = await fetchAPI(getArticles);
  const articlesData = await articles;

  const paths = articlesData.map((article) => ({
    params: { slug : article.slug }/*, locale: 'en-US'*/,
    //params: { slug : article.slug }, locale: 'fr-FR'
  }))

 
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params, locale }) {
 

  const res = await fetch(`${publicRuntimeConfig.API_URL}/articles?slug=${params.slug}`)
  let initialData = await res.json()
  let translationBySlug = undefined
  let translationById = undefined

  const resBlog = await fetchAPI(getBlog)
  const dataBlog = await resBlog;

 

  return {
    props: {
      article: initialData[0],
     
      blogDescription: dataBlog.banner,
    },
    revalidate: 60  60 * 24 //1 day,
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'featured_image' of undefined. [slug].js:320

Comment: But article.featured_image actually exist though. I believe the error is related with something else as everything works fine locally. And I was able to build with no probleme using SSR (getServerSideProps).
However I need to serve static content for my blog posts

Comment: Have you verified all the [possible ways to fix it?](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error#possible-ways-to-fix-it)

Comment: Thank you @PsyGik for mentionning that, the error was due to "fallback" set to "true". I set it to false and it is now working.